# trouble formulating an sql query

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to formulate a query which, given two tables: (1) Salespersons, (2) Sales; displays the id, name, and sum of sales brought in by the salesperson. The issue is that I can get the id and sum of brought in money but I don't know how  to add their names. Furthermore, my attempts omit the salespersons which did not sell anything, which is unfortunate.

In detail:

There are two naive tables:

```
create table Salespersons (
    id integer,
    name varchar(100)
);

create table Sales (
    sale_id integer,
    spsn_id integer,
    cstm_id integer, 
    paid_amt double
);
```

I want to make a query that for each Salesperson displays
their total sum of sales brought in.

This query comes to mind:

```
select spsn_id, sum(paid_amt) from Sales group by spsn_id
```

This query only returns list of ids and total amount brought
in, but not the names of the salespersons and it omits 
salespersons that sold nothing.

How can I make a query that for each salesperson in Salespersons
table, prints their id, name, sum of their sales, 0 if they
have sold nothing at all.

I appreciate any help!

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
select sp.id, sp.name, sum(s.paid_amt)
  from salespersons sp
  left join sales s
    on sp.id = s.spsn_id
 group by sp.id, sp.name
```

Comment: updated, ´cause I forgot to include the id :P, and it should be left join, as a salesperson cound have no sales

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT sp.id,sp.name,SUM(NVL(s.paid_amt,0))
FROM salespersons sp
LEFT JOIN sales s ON sp.id = s.spsn_id
GROUP BY sp.id, sp.name
```

The LEFT JOIN will return the salespersons even when they have no sales.

THE [NVL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0052627.html) will give you 0 whenever there is no sale for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
with t as
(select spsn_id, sum(paid_amt) as totamt
  from Sales 
  group by spsn_id 
)
select sp.id, sp.name, coalesce( t.totamt, 0 )
  from salespersons sp
  left join t  ON sp.id = t.spsn_id
```

Which (theoretically) does the grouping before the join, thus saving time.

Coalesce does the same thing here as NVL, but is more portable.